# ERROR: 177: ao tocar som AVAudioPlayer [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

Estou obtendo essa mensagem de erro quando toco um som,
erro tem acontecido sempre na primeira vez que toca o som, em alguns testes não aparece o erro e em outros sim..

```
var beep : AVAudioPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad()  {

        super.viewDidLoad()

          if let beep = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("beep", type:"wav") {
            self.beep = beep
        }


//SOM
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer?  {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }

    return audioPlayer
}

//Para tocar
            beep?.play()
```

Comment: É possível informar também um trecho do código que está utilizando para tocar o som?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues adicionei o código